# Command line tool to convert SVG to EMF (Enhanced Metafile)

Tags: conversion, svg, emf

I know I can use `Save as` in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) to convert from SVG to Enhanced Metafile (EMF). But if I have several files this is a bit cumbersome. Is there a command line tool I could use instead?

Comment: You saved my life by making me discover Inkscape. Works much better than AI for creating EMF !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you can use inkscape from the command lone to do this with the -M switch.

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: This option is not present in Inkscape 0.48.4 :(

Comment: @rumtscho AFAIK it is only available under Windows

Comment: @f3lix I don't remember the circumstances of making this comment, but there is a good chance I was on Linux. I was going to ask you how to do it on Linux then, but I guess this is offtopic enough to merit its own question.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to use bitmap export, I'd like to maintain it as a vector EMF file.

Comment: @Jason Just tested on OSX and it creates a vector emf for me.

Comment: Some notes: the options can not be set on cli but it will use the last settings that have been used from gui

Answer (score 23):

If you want the exact command to do this here it is:

```
$ inkscape --file <Input-file> --export-emf <output-file>
```

Comment: Side comment: You might want to install `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` to overcome the `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` Gtk-Message which is shown every time one executes the command.

Answer (score 20):

With Inkscape 1.0 the commands changed. And since this is the top Google result, I thought it might be worth to update the answer:

```
inkscape filename.svg --export-filename filename.emf
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer today (version 1.0.1)

Comment: I tried all online tools in first page of google search "svg to emf", but they add black background while converting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1glhwDJsjiDNLF3flmpgtIVfurum29xcQ/view?usp=sharing) svg to emf. Same is the case of above command.

Comment: With `inskscape --export-type="emf" myartwork.svg` you can skip explicitly naming the output file.