# On Linux, how to export .svg files into a vector format readable by Powerpoint?

Tags: linux, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, vector-graphics, svg

I am working on a Linux computer, and have a bunch of .svg files. I have to give them to a client who will insert them into a Powerpoint presentation (the client is working on a Windows machine). I am supposed to deliver the files ready for the insertion; the format conversion has to happen on my machine. The files have to stay in a vector format, because the graphics to be freely resizeable within the Powerpoint presentation.

I thought that I could export them as EMF. I found multiple sources stating that Inkscape can export EMF, only to learn [that it is an Windows-only feature](https://superuser.com/questions/440071/command-line-tool-to-convert-svg-to-emf-enhanced-metafile).

Is there a way, through EMF or something else, to get my .svg files converted to a Powerpoint-readable vector format?

Comment: What formats does PowerPoint accept? I would expect `convert` from ImageMagic to be able to do this though I have sometimes had problems with .svg files. You could also export the svgs as large bitmaps with enough resolution that resizing won't be a problem.

Comment: As an aside, while graphics will remain vector as EMF, the grouping will change from the SVG version which may be an issue for the client. I have found no reliable way of transferring groups to a PPT readable format.

Answer (score 3):

You could try converting SVG to EMF with Google Code's Java [svg2emf](https://code.google.com/p/svg2emf/).

> converts SVG(Scalable Vector Graphics) files to EMF(Enhanced Meta
>   File) files using batik and FreeHEP VectorGraphics library

Answer (score 1):

As there's no accepted answer yet here's an alternative: modern versions of powerpoint are supposed to be able to import .PDF, and inkscape can export that very nicely.  So if the client's powerpoint installation is recent-ish that could provide a route.