# Bulk convert SVG to EMF

Tags: inkscape, svg, image-processing, emf

I have several SVG images which I want to bulk convert to EMF (and possibly WMF also) format. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1glhwDJsjiDNLF3flmpgtIVfurum29xcQ/view?usp=sharing) is one of the images.

I tried all online tools in first page of google search "svg to emf", but they add black background for transparent areas while converting this svg to emf.

I also tried inkscape command:

```
inkscape filename.svg --export-filename filename.emf
```

as suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579739/594287) answer. But it also adds black background for transparent areas.
Is there any way in which I can bulk convert several SVGs to EMFs (and if possible also WMF) without adding black background for transparancy?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but this answer is may provide clarity for anyone searching for why they cannot convert their images without artifacts.

First of all, EMF does not support transparency.

The problem with your file is that there are extra paths behind the graphs. If you go to Layers > Layers and Objects you will see the following once you expand the groups:
[The highlighted path is the culprit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhsC.png)

Once you remove both paths from both groups and save it you will get a nice and tidy EMF [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aRJl.png).